# I am trying to load content one website to another in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

I need to get content from another website so that I have used curl package to achieve this. After the request, contents are getting from another website. But after some time it is going to blank page. So I have tested in the inspect tab. I am getting the below error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 93512 of the JSON data
Stack trace:
```

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    "accept: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: e0f90ce8-80bf-2630-2ea9-1b7924ecbbeb"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
exit;
```

Why I am getting the blank page. I did not find any errors in my PHP code. Could anyone help to resolve this problem
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is coming from Javascript, not PHP, so is not coming from this code block.

Comment: Your error is in the frontend. Show us the ajax request that you are passing the data to the frontend